# Проверить, включен ли режим тёмной темы в Android 9 или 10?

Tags: java, android

Как проверить, включен ли режим тёмной темы в Android 9 или 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme

Разве не оно?

```
int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // ночная тема не активна, используется светлая тема
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // ночная тема активна, и она используется
        break;
}
```